# Display and save plot simultaneously in maxima

Tags: maxima

Currently, I can display the plot in maxima as follows:

```
f(x) := sin(x)$
g(x) := cos(x)$

plot2d([f(x), g(x)], [x,-5,5],[legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"],
[xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
[gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"])$
```

And save the plots with the command:

```
plot2d([f(x), g(x)], [x,-5,5],[legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"],
[xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
[pdf_file,"./trigplot.pdf"],
[gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"]
)$
```

How to display and save the plot in maxima simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p2` takes a file name and the same arguments as `plot2d`.

```
p2(file, [L])::=buildq([file, L],
  (plot2d(splice(L)),
   plot2d(splice(L), ['pdf_file, file])))$

f(x) := sin(x)$
g(x) := cos(x)$
p2("trigplot.pdf",
  [f(x), g(x)], [x,-5,5],
  [legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"], 
  [xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
  [gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"]);
```

It is [a macro](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_7.html#IDX238). First it substitutes `file` and `L`. splice(L)` is converted to an argument list. After the substitution the resulting expression is evaluated in the context of the caller.

You can use `macroexpand` to see the expression after substitution.

```
(%i1) a: 42 $
(%i2) macroexpand(p2(file, a, b));
(%o2)           (plot2d(a, b), plot2d(a, b, ['pdf_file, file]))
```

Comment: Only changed the filename to `"./trigplot.pdf"` to save the plot in the current directory.